# Auto sliding photos jQuery image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script which runs a function when clicking the next arrow to go to the next photo.

```
<script src="js/jquery.cbpFWSlider.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make an automatic call to this function or whatever to slide photos?

```
        $( function() {
            $( '#cbp-fwslider' ).cbpFWSlider( {speed : 1200, easing : 'ease'});
        } );
```

Also how can I modify the **easing : 'ease'** param. to other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. You can find the answer here [Autoplay JQuery slideshow Using cbpFWSlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927466/autoplay-jquery-slideshow-using-cbpfwslider)

```
$('document').ready(function(){
                // init slider
                $('#cbp-fwslider').cbpFWSlider();

               /**
                     Set a 3 seconds interval
                     if next button is visible (so is not the last slide)  click next button
                     else it finds first dot and click it to start from the 1st slide
                **/
                setInterval( function(){
                    if($('.cbp-fwnext').is(":visible"))
                        {
                            $('.cbp-fwnext').click();   


                }
                else{
                        $('.cbp-fwdots').find('span').click();
                    }
            } ,3000 );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way of getting the result you want, but try using `window.setInterval( func, delay );` where delay is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank You but I will try smth else.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin uses the easing option to apply a CSS3 property "transition-timing-function" to the function. To change the easing value, specify another valid value.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp as a reference.