# I need my jquery slider to auto play

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, autoplay

I have a jquery slider from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/full-width-image-slider/

I have installed the slider perfectly and its working fine, I need it to slide automatically when a user visits the website.

I have no experience with jQuery and I'm unable to get this to autoplay.

Here is the jQuery code for the slider;

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

// global
var Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

$.CBPFWSlider = function( options, element ) {
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );
};

// the options
$.CBPFWSlider.defaults = {

    // default transition speed (ms)
    speed : 500,
    // default transition easing
    easing : 'ease'
};

$.CBPFWSlider.prototype = {
    _init : function( options ) {
        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.CBPFWSlider.defaults, options );
        // cache some elements and initialize some variables
        this._config();
        // initialize/bind the events
        this._initEvents();
    },
    _config : function() {

        // the list of items
        this.$list = this.$el.children( 'ul' );
        // the items (li elements)
        this.$items = this.$list.children( 'li' );
        // total number of items
        this.itemsCount = this.$items.length;
        // support for CSS Transitions & transforms
        this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms;
        this.support3d = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
        // transition end event name and transform name
        // transition end event name
        var transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition' : 'transitionend'
            },
            transformNames = {
                'WebkitTransform' : '-webkit-transform',
                'MozTransform' : '-moz-transform',
                'OTransform' : '-o-transform',
                'msTransform' : '-ms-transform',
                'transform' : 'transform'
            };

        if( this.support ) {
            this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ] + '.cbpFWSlider';
            this.transformName = transformNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transform' ) ];
        }
        // current and old item´s index
        this.current = 0;
        this.old = 0;
        // check if the list is currently moving
        this.isAnimating = false;
        // the list (ul) will have a width of 100% x itemsCount
        this.$list.css( 'width', 100 * this.itemsCount + '%' );
        // apply the transition
        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.css( 'transition', this.transformName + ' ' + this.options.speed + 'ms ' + this.options.easing );
        }
        // each item will have a width of 100 / itemsCount
        this.$items.css( 'width', 100 / this.itemsCount + '%' );
        // add navigation arrows and the navigation dots if there is more than 1 item
        if( this.itemsCount > 1 ) {

            // add navigation arrows (the previous arrow is not shown initially):
            this.$navPrev = $( '<span class="cbp-fwprev">&lt;</span>' ).hide();
            this.$navNext = $( '<span class="cbp-fwnext">&gt;</span>' );
            $( '<nav/>' ).append( this.$navPrev, this.$navNext ).appendTo( this.$el );
            // add navigation dots
            var dots = '';
            for( var i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; ++i ) {
                // current dot will have the class cbp-fwcurrent
                var dot = i === this.current ? '<span class="cbp-fwcurrent"></span>' : '<span></span>';
                dots += dot;
            }
            var navDots = $( '<div class="cbp-fwdots"/>' ).append( dots ).appendTo( this.$el );
            this.$navDots = navDots.children( 'span' );

        }

    },
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;
        if( this.itemsCount > 1 ) {
            this.$navPrev.on( 'click.cbpFWSlider', $.proxy( this._navigate, this, 'previous' ) );
            this.$navNext.on( 'click.cbpFWSlider', $.proxy( this._navigate, this, 'next' ) );
            this.$navDots.on( 'click.cbpFWSlider', function() { self._jump( $( this ).index() ); } );
        }

    },
    _navigate : function( direction ) {

        // do nothing if the list is currently moving
        if( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }

        this.isAnimating = true;
        // update old and current values
        this.old = this.current;
        if( direction === 'next' && this.current < this.itemsCount - 1 ) {
            ++this.current;
        }
        else if( direction === 'previous' && this.current > 0 ) {
            --this.current;
        }
        // slide
        this._slide();

    },
    _slide : function() {

        // check which navigation arrows should be shown
        this._toggleNavControls();
        // translate value
        var translateVal = -1 * this.current * 100 / this.itemsCount;
        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.css( 'transform', this.support3d ? 'translate3d(' + translateVal + '%,0,0)' : 'translate(' + translateVal + '%)' );
        }
        else {
            this.$list.css( 'margin-left', -1 * this.current * 100 + '%' ); 
        }

        var transitionendfn = $.proxy( function() {
            this.isAnimating = false;
        }, this );

        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.on( this.transEndEventName, $.proxy( transitionendfn, this ) );
        }
        else {
            transitionendfn.call();
        }

    },
    _toggleNavControls : function() {

        // if the current item is the first one in the list, the left arrow is not shown
        // if the current item is the last one in the list, the right arrow is not shown
        switch( this.current ) {
            case 0 : this.$navNext.show(); this.$navPrev.hide(); break;
            case this.itemsCount - 1 : this.$navNext.hide(); this.$navPrev.show(); break;
            default : this.$navNext.show(); this.$navPrev.show(); break;
        }
        // highlight navigation dot
        this.$navDots.eq( this.old ).removeClass( 'cbp-fwcurrent' ).end().eq( this.current ).addClass( 'cbp-fwcurrent' );

    },
    _jump : function( position ) {

        // do nothing if clicking on the current dot, or if the list is currently moving
        if( position === this.current || this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;
        // update old and current values
        this.old = this.current;
        this.current = position;
        // slide
        this._slide();

    },
    destroy : function() {

        if( this.itemsCount > 1 ) {
            this.$navPrev.parent().remove();
            this.$navDots.parent().remove();
        }
        this.$list.css( 'width', 'auto' );
        if( this.support ) {
            this.$list.css( 'transition', 'none' );
        }
        this.$items.css( 'width', 'auto' );

    }
};

var logError = function( message ) {
    if ( window.console ) {
        window.console.error( message );
    }
};

$.fn.cbpFWSlider = function( options ) {
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
        this.each(function() {
            var instance = $.data( this, 'cbpFWSlider' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on cbpFWSlider prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }
            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for cbpFWSlider instance" );
                return;
            }
            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        });
    } 
    else {
        this.each(function() {  
            var instance = $.data( this, 'cbpFWSlider' );
            if ( instance ) {
                instance._init();
            }
            else {
                instance = $.data( this, 'cbpFWSlider', new $.CBPFWSlider( options, this ) );
            }
        });
    }
    return this;
};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

I have looked at different threads but I haven't got any understanding on where to put the autoplay code in the jQuery file.

Can anyone anyone help me on where I need to add the autoplay function?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        // init slider
        $('#cbp-fwslider').cbpFWSlider();
        /**
              Set a 3 seconds interval
              if next button is visible (so is not the last slide)  click next button
              else it finds first dot and click it to start from the 1st slide
         **/
        setInterval(function () {
            if ($('.cbp-fwnext').is(":visible")) {
                $('.cbp-fwnext').click();
            }
            else {
                $('.cbp-fwdots').find('span').click();
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
```

You can use below code to solve your problem and slide the images automatically every three seconds..If you want to change the time,change that 3000 as you wish.

Below is the link that i copy the code from:

[Autoplay JQuery slideshow Using cbpFWSlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927466/autoplay-jquery-slideshow-using-cbpfwslider)

Comment: thanks for replying. where do i put this code though? this is where i dont know where to go next. do i put it in the jquery file or at the bottom of my html? thanks

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of my html. works perfect

Thanks so much :)