# Jquery slider not working auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a running slider. I want this slider to auto run and onclick, Its working onclick. I just to make it work on auto run.

```
[Demo][1]
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/fwbgy154/
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927466/autoplay-jquery-slideshow-using-cbpfwslider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/fwbgy154/1/

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
            // init slider
            $('#cbp-fwslider').cbpFWSlider();

            setInterval( function(){
                if($('.cbp-fwnext').is(":visible")){
                        $('.cbp-fwnext').click();   
                }else {
                    $('.cbp-fwdots').find('span').click();
                }
            } ,3000 );
    });
```

Slider is automatically sliding now.

Referred to this one -> [Autoplay JQuery slideshow Using cbpFWSlider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927466/autoplay-jquery-slideshow-using-cbpfwslider) ..

Comment: Thanks M.Matias. Is it possible to keep the arrow buttons. Right now one gets hide when the last slide done.

Comment: It's because it's already the last slide, so no available next slide. Same as no previous arrow when the first slide is shown. Do you need them always visible?

Comment: Don't worry M.Matias, I will for sure check you answer. Yes I visible all the time. Is it possible.? Thanks

Comment: Can you please help in this last issue? I want them to visible all the time. Thanks

Comment: Maybe add something like **$('.cbp-fwnext').show();** and **$('.cbp-fwprev').show();** and it will make the arrows visible.